# Displaying Background image with in-line styling in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import Slick from 'react-slick';
import style from './Slider.module.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const SliderTemplates = (props) => {

    let template = null;
    const settings= {
        dots:true,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow:1,
        slidesToScroll:1
    }

    switch(props.type){
        case('featured'):
            template= props.data.map((item, i)=>{
                return(
                    <div key={i}>
                        <div className={style.featured_item}>
                            <div 
                                className={style.featured_image} 
                                style={{ background: `url(../../Assets/images/articles/${item.image})` }}>
                                <Link to={`/articles/${item.id}`}>
                                    <div className={style.featured_caption}>
                                    {item.title}s
                                    </div>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            break;
        default: 
            template=null;
    }
    return (
        <Slick {...settings}> 
            {template}
        </Slick>
    );
};

export default SliderTemplates;
```

```css
.featured_item{
    position: relative;
}
.feature_item a{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    right: 0px;
}
.featured_image {
    height: 330px;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
.featured_caption{
    color: #fff;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 28px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I am trying to map images from a folder (Address given in the picture attached) with in-line styling in ReactJs.
All the data is imported from db.json and I want to display the images(position: relative) with text (position: absolute) but the picture is not available for display and I can't find where I went wrong.
The picture is not displayed.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCqC7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

style={{ backgroundImage: `url(../../Assets/images/articles/${item.image})` }}>`

Also consider placing your images in the public folder instead - static assets work best there. By doing this you could use this approach:

`style={{ backgroundImage:`url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/articles/${item.image})`

Read more about static assets in React here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: this solution works: Also consider placing your images in the public folder instead - static assets work best there. By doing this you could use this approach:

style={{ backgroundImage:url(${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/articles/${item.image})`

Read more about static assets in React here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/


thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to set the background image the css property is `BackGroundImage`.Secondly you need to import the Images from the folder, this is how you would do that

```
style={{ BackGroundImage: `url(${require('../../Assets/images/articles/'+item.image+''})` }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the image into a folder in react and set it as a background image you would in regular css

```
.featured_image {
    height: 330px;
    background: url('./(IMAGE PATH HERE)') no-repeat center center / cover
}
```

Just one to note also, i would always give your styles a capital letter if you are using .module.css and do not use - or _ , i would recommend renaming to .FeaturedImage, and then change it in your jsx - className={style.FeaturedImage}

Comment: this would not work , the data is being fetched in a loop and each item has it's own image i.e `item.image` . the code above would assign the same background image to every item

Comment: Yes, as per @AbdullahAbid 's comment, your method won't work because I am trying to map the images.